# Jenkins Build Failure with Workspace

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am getting a Failure build message from Jenkins when I build my project. I am not sure what this entails. This build has worked multiple times before up until one of my other team members committed new Data to our SVN server. Now the build does not "Recognize" the Workspace. There was a [link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10222) which had the same error but it did not solve my problem at the end.

```
Started by user Chris Parsons
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\iLaundry - Installer Builder\workspace
Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\iLaundry - Installer Builder\workspace
Cleaning local Directory .
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\iLaundry - Installer Builder\workspace\.\.svn\wc.db: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:239)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:307)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:298)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:75)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:161)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:169)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:133)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:161)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1004)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:985)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:961)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:916)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:889)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:910)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:845)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1411)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:652)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:557)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer while I was busy with another problem. Jenkins built out of the `${JENKINS_HOME}/Workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}` folder, but the project I am building has it's own Workspace so all I needed to do was change the dir. and it worked perfectly.

Comment: how do u fix that issue, I have also the same problem,